# Logic Apps HTTP Failure - You do not have permission to perform this action

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I triggered a logic app that worked perfectly yesterday however today I am getting an "InternalServerError" on the HTTP request

`"body": "{\"message\":\"You do not have permission to perform this action.\",\"code\":0}"`

I am the owner of the resource group the logic app is in, but just for extra good measure I have added the Logic Apps Contributor role to my account, but alas it is still erroring.

I've even rebuilt the workflow, checked all connections and everything independently is working fine, it's just when I hit the HTTP request.

The API request runs through Postman fine, so something funky is happening in Azure. I've spoken to my Azure administrator who is certain nothing has changed between yesterday and today.

Any thoughts on what I can check to see why this is happening all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

I test it in my side with an account which has own role of the resource group. It works fine in my side.

So I think it is a transient issue. I think it's an issue of account permissions which may be caused by cache. Please logout your account and new inprivate window from browser, then login again in the new window and try request the logic app.